# Problems inserting data from user into database using Java

Tags: java, sql, database, bufferedreader

I've got a database that includes a movie table, I'm trying to write a java program to receive input from the user and insert it into the database. My code is below. I've included the whole code as I'm not sure why I'm getting the errors.

For each of the `stmt.set...` lines I am receiving, for example:

> error: cannot find symbol - stmt.setString(fname);

I can't figure out why I'd be getting this as I've received the input from the user and assigned it to this variable before inserting.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class insert {
    public static void main(String [] argv) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost//////";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "/////", "///");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter the id for the new movie: ");
            String id = bufRead.readLine();
            int id_int = Integer.parseInt(id);
            System.out.println("Please enter the title for the new movie: ");
            String title = bufRead.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the director's first name: ");
            String fname = bufRead.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the director's last name: ");
            String lname = bufRead.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the genre of the movie: ");
            String genre = bufRead.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the media type: ");
            String media = bufRead.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the movie's release date: ");
            String date = bufRead.readLine();
            java.sql.Date release_d = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
            System.out.println("Please enter the movie's studio: ");
            String studio = bufRead.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the retail price of the movie: ");
            String price = bufRead.readLine();
            double price_d = Double.parseDouble(price);
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of copies in stock: ");
            String stock = bufRead.readLine();
            int stock_int = Integer.parseInt(stock);

        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err);
        } catch (NumberFormatException err) {
            System.out.println(err);
        }

        System.out.println("\nWelcome to MovieDirect");
        System.out.println();

        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO movie " + "(movie_id, movie_title, director_first_name, director_last_name, genre, media_type, release_date, studio_name, retail_price, current_stock)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            stmt.setInt(1, id_int);
            stmt.setString(2, title);
            stmt.setString(3, fname);
            stmt.setString(4, lname);
            stmt.setString(5, genre);
            stmt.setString(6, media);
            stmt.setDate(7, release_d);
            stmt.setString(8, studio);
            stmt.setDouble(9, price_d);
            stmt.setString(10, stock_int);

            stmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            conn.close();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("\nSuccess! ");
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @shmosel For every stmt.set... line it points to the variable within the parentheses and gives "error: cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, your error looks like it's talking about `setString` and so on, but it's actually about the **variables** you're passing to those methods.

All of the variables `id_int`, `title`, `fname`, `lname`, etc. were all declared in a **different scope**: the other `try` block.

To fix it, declare all of those variables outside of the `try` blocks (just like how you did with `conn`), so that they will be in-scope for all of the `try` blocks.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I really should have realised that haha. 
It's saying I have to initialise them first, which is fine except for the date. Do you know how I'm supposed to initialise the sql date by any chance?

Comment: Similar to what you did with `conn`, you can "trick" your compiler by assigning `null` or `0` to all of them. Just make sure that later you do a check that they aren't still `null` when you enter your block with the `PreparedStatement` (just in case there was an `IOException` or something in the block that set the values to those variables).